# Wraptable producing unwanted indent in next Section

Tags: wrapfigure, wrap

My code is:

```
\begin{wraptable}{l}{0.15\textwidth}
    \vspace{-20pt}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc|c}
        $a$&$b$&$c$&$\operatorname{f}$ \\ \hline
        0 &0 &0 &0 \\
        0 &0 &1 &1 \\
        0 &1 &0 &1 \\
        0 &1 &1 &0 \\
        1 &0 &0 &1 \\
        1 &0 &1 &0 \\
        1 &1 &0 &1 \\
        1 &1 &1 &0
    \end{tabular}
\end{wraptable}
\noindent Consider an example:
\subsection{Example 1}
$\operatorname{f}(a,b,c)=\bar{a}\bar{b}c+\bar{a}b\bar{c}+a\bar{b}\bar{c}+ab\bar{c}$ \vspace{5pt}

Sum of all the Minterms for which the function assumes a value of 1 is called the Canonical Sum of Products.

$\operatorname{f}(a,b,c)=\Sigma(1,2,4,6)$

\vspace{10pt}\hrule
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\noindent
\section{Canonical Product of Sums}
```

The Output is :
[image: Unwanted Space Before Section 1.6]

Note the unwanted indented space before Section 1.6.

I tried using \vspace to see if the indentation goes away -- it doesn't.
Next I tried using \noindent, to no use.

How do I make the text normal again? Please help.

Comment: Wraptig assumes every line is \baselineskip apart, which is not the case here.  Use \WFclear to force the wrap to cease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in this case the text is not actually wrapping around the tabular, you might use a `minipage` instead.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newsavebox\tempbox

\begin{document}
\savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{tabular}[t]{ccc|c}
        $a$&$b$&$c$&$\operatorname{f}$ \\ \hline
        0 &0 &0 &0 \\
        0 &0 &1 &1 \\
        0 &1 &0 &1 \\
        0 &1 &1 &0 \\
        1 &0 &0 &1 \\
        1 &0 &1 &0 \\
        1 &1 &0 &1 \\
        1 &1 &1 &0
\end{tabular}}
\noindent\usebox{\tempbox}\hspace{\columnsep}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \textwidth-\wd\tempbox-\columnsep}
\noindent Consider an example:
\subsection{Example 1}
\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{f}(a,b,c)=\bar{a}\bar{b}c+\bar{a}b\bar{c}+a\bar{b}\bar{c}+ab\bar{c}
\end{equation*}
Sum of all the Minterms for which the function assumes a value of 1 is called the Canonical Sum of Products.
\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{f}(a,b,c)=\Sigma(1,2,4,6)
\end{equation*}
\hrule height0pt% force vspace after equation
\end{minipage}\par\hrule
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\noindent
\section{Canonical Product of Sums}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]